# Sort users by activity

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to sort users by the last_active column, while it is important to display online users (`last_active> = datetime.utcnow () - timedelta (minutes = 5)`) at the top of the list sorted by ID.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True, nullable=False)
    last_active = db.Column(db.DateTime)


def get_result():
    online_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5)
    users= User.query.order_by(case(
            (User.last_active >= online_time, online_time),
            else_=User.last_active).desc())

    return users.limit(10).all()
```

I am catching the following error:

```
File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 2431, in __init__
    whenlist = [
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 2433, in <listcomp>
    for (c, r) in whens
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 432, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 759, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 432, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
    
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 67, in operate
    return o[0](self.expr, op, *(other + o[1:]), **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 237, in _getitem_impl
    _unsupported_impl(expr, op, other, **kw)
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 241, in _unsupported_impl
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

The option to first get the list and then sort is not particularly interesting. I am trying to implement a valid query using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: The first argument to `case()` should be a list of tuples, not just the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting separate users online and offline with different sortings and adding up the results:

```py
def get_result():
    online_time = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5)
    users_online = User.query.filter(User.last_active >= online_time) \
        .order_by(User.last_active.desc())
    users_offline = User.query.filter(User.last_active < online_time) \
        .order_by(User.id.asc())

    return users_online.limit(10).all() + users_offline.limit(10).all()
```